# Aligning anchor text right on a GAS app

Tags: gwt, google-apps-script

Im having a problem aligning an anchor text "instructions" to right on https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwvCnn7WfTWsU2sz-8ONeM_gLM_y5pZd31s6lb68bjyx1bETOyy/exec 
Here is the code>>

```
//App instruction
var instlink =  app.createAnchor('Instructions', 'https://sites.google.com/site/1000eventz/')
  .setStyleAttribute('text-align', 'right')
  .setHorizontalAlignment(UiApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT)
  .setId('instlink');
```

More code>>
https://script.google.com/d/1H6DLb8L6Qd3g55Dzn_A7ed61QvM_OcrLINDfya1i1h7JAyV_jLH7nmcq/edit

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the widtget to a HorizontalPanel, set it's width to 100% and this panel's HorizontalAlignment to UiApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT.
Finally add this HorizontalPanel (holding the widget) where you previously added the anchor widget.

This is just off the top of my head coding, i haven't tested it but it should work.

Let me know, i hope it helps.